# Generate permutations of list with repeated elements

Tags: python, permutation

In Python, it is quite simple to produce all permutations of a list using the `itertools` module. I have a situation where the sequence I'm using only has two characters (i.e. `'1122'`). I want to generate all unique permutations.

For the string `'1122'`, there are 6 unique permutations (`1122`, `1212`, `1221`, etc), but `itertools.permutations` will yield 24 items. It's simple to only record the unique permutations, but it will take much longer than necessary to collect them as all 720 items are considered.

Is there a function or module that accounts for repeated elements when generating permutations so I don't have to write my own?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This web page](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/04/lexicographic-permutations-using.html) looks promising.

```
def next_permutation(seq, pred=cmp):
    """Like C++ std::next_permutation() but implemented as
    generator. Yields copies of seq."""
    def reverse(seq, start, end):
        # seq = seq[:start] + reversed(seq[start:end]) + \
        #       seq[end:]
        end -= 1
        if end <= start:
            return
        while True:
            seq[start], seq[end] = seq[end], seq[start]
            if start == end or start+1 == end:
                return
            start += 1
            end -= 1
    if not seq:
        raise StopIteration
    try:
        seq[0]
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("seq must allow random access.")
    first = 0
    last = len(seq)
    seq = seq[:]
    # Yield input sequence as the STL version is often
    # used inside do {} while.
    yield seq[:]
    if last == 1:
        raise StopIteration
    while True:
        next = last - 1
        while True:
            # Step 1.
            next1 = next
            next -= 1
            if pred(seq[next], seq[next1]) < 0:
                # Step 2.
                mid = last - 1
                while not (pred(seq[next], seq[mid]) < 0):
                    mid -= 1
                seq[next], seq[mid] = seq[mid], seq[next]
                # Step 3.
                reverse(seq, next1, last)
                # Change to yield references to get rid of
                # (at worst) |seq|! copy operations.
                yield seq[:]
                break
            if next == first:
                raise StopIteration
    raise StopIteration

>>> for p in next_permutation([int(c) for c in "111222"]):
...     print p
... 
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

---

2017-08-12

Seven years later, here is a better algorithm (better for clarity):

```
from itertools import permutations

def unique_perms(series):
    return {"".join(p) for p in permutations(series)}

print(sorted(unique_perms('1122')))
```

Comment: Is it OK that `reverse` is used on each iteration? It has `O(n)` complexity, and the fact it's run on every iteration may make the whole algorithm pretty slow.

Comment: I modified the code a bit for it to be more to the point and reflect the names used to describe the algorithm in the Knuth's book. For those who need it I post the link: https://ideone.com/juG94

Comment: Also, I have rewritten this algorithm using more functional style coding (with generators). It's a few times slower than the version working directly with indexes. Still, the main part of the algorithm (beginning with `while True:`) looks more clear in this version. The code is here: https://ideone.com/mvu1y

Comment: Nice work, but I can not realize why it does not work with zeros in the sequence

Comment: Something wrong with this algorithm, it is also dependent on the initial order in sequence. Sequences [1,1,2,2,2] and [2,1,1,2,2] lead to different number of permutations.

Comment: Should I always sort my sequence before?

Comment: @freude: this function iterates until it reaches the largest lexicographical permutation, *then stops*. Therefore, to obtain all permutations, make sure to sort your input (so that it is the lowest permutation, lexicographically).

Comment: Using `list()` around this iterator does _not_ work: `list(next_permutation([1, 2]))` gives `[[2, 1], [2, 1]]`. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Fixed it. (A copy in the first `yield` was missing.)

Answer (score 17):

### *More Itertools* has a function for this:

> **[`more-itertools.distinct_permutations(iterable)`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations)**
>
> Yields successive distinct permutations of the elements in *iterable*.
>
> Equivalent to `set(permutations(iterable))`, except duplicates are not
> generated and thrown away. For larger input sequences, **this is much
> more efficient**.

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

for p in distinct_permutations('1122'):
    print(''.join(p))

# 2211
# 2121
# 1221
# 2112
# 1212
# 1122
```

Installation:

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Comment: undoubtedly the neatest answer

Answer (score 2):

> Using set makes solution simpler. Strings with repeated chars, and
> non repeated,
> used as input.

```
from itertools import permutations

def perm(s):
    return set(permutations(s))
    
    l = '1122'
    
    perm(l)
  
    {('1', '1', '2', '2'),
     ('1', '2', '1', '2'),
     ('1', '2', '2', '1'),
     ('2', '1', '1', '2'),
     ('2', '1', '2', '1'),
     ('2', '2', '1', '1')}
    
    
    l2 = '1234'
    
    perm(l2)

    {('1', '2', '3', '4'),
     ('1', '2', '4', '3'),
     ('1', '3', '2', '4'),
     ('1', '3', '4', '2'),
     ('1', '4', '2', '3'),
     ('1', '4', '3', '2'),
     ('2', '1', '3', '4'),
     ('2', '1', '4', '3'),
     ('2', '3', '1', '4'),
     ('2', '3', '4', '1'),
     ('2', '4', '1', '3'),
     ('2', '4', '3', '1'),
     ('3', '1', '2', '4'),
     ('3', '1', '4', '2'),
     ('3', '2', '1', '4'),
     ('3', '2', '4', '1'),
     ('3', '4', '1', '2'),
     ('3', '4', '2', '1'),
     ('4', '1', '2', '3'),
     ('4', '1', '3', '2'),
     ('4', '2', '1', '3'),
     ('4', '2', '3', '1'),
     ('4', '3', '1', '2'),
     ('4', '3', '2', '1')}
```

Comment: The following is sufficient and concise: set(permutations(s))

Comment: @LelandHepworth, Yes, you are correct. There was no need for using re or list.

Answer (score 1):

This is also a common interview question. In the event standard library [modules](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) can't be used, here is an implementation to consider:

> We define a [lexicographic ordering of permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order). Once we do
>   that we can just start with the *smallest* permutation and increment
>   it minimally till we reach the *largest* permutation.

```
def next_permutation_helper(perm):
    if not perm:
        return perm

    n = len(perm)

    """
    Find k such that p[k] < p[k + l] and entries after index k appear in
    decreasing order.
    """
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        if not perm[i - 1] >= perm[i]:
            break

    # k refers to the inversion point
    k = i - 1

    # Permutation is already the max it can be
    if k == -1:
        return []

    """
    Find the smallest p[l] such that p[l] > p[k]
    (such an l must exist since p[k] < p[k + 1].
    Swap p[l] and p[k]
    """
    for i in range(n - 1, k, -1):
        if not perm[k] >= perm[i]:
            perm[i], perm[k] = perm[k], perm[i]
            break

    # Reverse the sequence after position k.
    perm[k + 1 :] = reversed(perm[k + 1 :])

    return perm


def multiset_permutation(A):
    """
    We sort array first and `next_permutation()` will ensure we generate
    permutations in lexicographic order
    """
    A = sorted(A)
    result = list()

    while True:
        result.append(A.copy())
        A = next_permutation_helper(A)
        if not A:
            break

    return result
```

Output:

```
>>> multiset_permutation([1, 1, 2, 2])
[[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1]]
```

You can transform the output from the mutable list to string using [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on this line:

```
result.append("".join(map(str, A.copy())))
```

to get:

```
['1122', '1212', '1221', '2112', '2121', '2211']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from more_itertools import distinct_permutations

x = [p for p in distinct_permutations(['M','I','S', 'S', 'I'])]

for item in x:
    
  print(item)
```

Output:

```
('I', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'M')
('S', 'I', 'S', 'I', 'M')
('S', 'S', 'I', 'I', 'M')
('I', 'S', 'I', 'S', 'M')
('S', 'I', 'I', 'S', 'M')
('I', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'M')
('I', 'S', 'I', 'M', 'S')
('S', 'I', 'I', 'M', 'S')
('I', 'I', 'S', 'M', 'S')
('I', 'I', 'M', 'S', 'S')
('I', 'S', 'S', 'M', 'I')
('S', 'I', 'S', 'M', 'I')
('S', 'S', 'I', 'M', 'I')
('S', 'S', 'M', 'I', 'I')
('I', 'S', 'M', 'S', 'I')
('S', 'I', 'M', 'S', 'I')
('S', 'M', 'I', 'S', 'I')
('S', 'M', 'S', 'I', 'I')
('I', 'M', 'S', 'S', 'I')
('M', 'I', 'S', 'S', 'I')
('M', 'S', 'I', 'S', 'I')
('M', 'S', 'S', 'I', 'I')
('I', 'S', 'M', 'I', 'S')
('S', 'I', 'M', 'I', 'S')
('S', 'M', 'I', 'I', 'S')
('I', 'M', 'S', 'I', 'S')
('M', 'I', 'S', 'I', 'S')
('M', 'S', 'I', 'I', 'S')
('I', 'M', 'I', 'S', 'S')
('M', 'I', 'I', 'S', 'S')
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, likely similar to what is used by `more_itertools`, which takes advantage of the lexicographical order of permutations as suggested by [@Brayoni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61940561/2988730), can be done by building an index of the iterable.

Let's say you have `L = '1122'`. You can build a very simple index with something like this:

```
index = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(L))}
```

Let's say you have a permutation `P` of `L`. It does not matter how many elements `P` has. Lexicographical ordering dictates that if you map `P` to using the index, it must always increase. Map `P` like this:

```
mapped = tuple(index[e] for e in p)  # or tuple(map(index.__getitem__, p))
```

Now you can discard elements that are less than or equal to the maximum seen so far:

```
def perm_with_dupes(it, n=None):
    it = tuple(it)   # permutations will do this anyway
    if n is None:
        n = len(it)
    index = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(it)}
    maximum = (-1,) * (len(it) if n is None else n)
    for perm in permutations(it, n):
        key = tuple(index[e] for e in perm)
        if key <= maximum: continue
        maximum = key
        yield perm
```

Notice that there is no additional memory overhead past keeping the last maximum item around. You can join the tuples with `''` if you like.