# python: weird list elements combination

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have the two following lists:

```
l1 = [1, 2, ,3]  
l2 = [x, y]
```

And would like to have all lists of 5 elements keeping the order of `l1` only. Say:

```
[x, y, 1, 2, 3],  
[x, 1, y, 2, 3],  
[x, 1, 2, y, 3],  
[x, 1, 2, 3, y],  
[y, x, 1, 2, 3],  
[y, 1, x, 2, 3],  
[y, 1, 2, x, 3],  
[y, 1, 2, 3, x],  
[1, x, y, 2, 3],  
[1, x, 2, y, 3],  
[1, x, 2, 3, y],  
[1, y, x, 2, 3],  
[1, y, 2, x, 3],  
[1, y, 2, 3, x],  
...  
[1, 2, 3, y, x],  
...  
[1, 2, 3, x, y]
```

Observe that the order of `l1` is important and `l2` is not. `l2` elements run over l1+l2 positions but only the order of `l1` is important. 
I'm struggling with this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Marcin: I really dislike that question; why would people be asking a question if they weren't having trouble figuring out where to start? There are some questions which merit that ("do my homework" questions), but I don't feel this is one of them.

Comment: This is not my home work. This is a over simplification of my problem. I work with protein sequence alignments and get stuck. Can't figure out how the best way to deal with this problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ninjagecko (a) Whether or not it's homework, this amounts to "write some combinatorial code for me for free" (b) some code illuminates both the goal and what the specific problem is.

Comment: Be respectful! I don't make money doing code. I'm a physicist making some research in structural biology for a rehumatic fever vaccine development. I began with python few months ago and couldn't be able deal with this problem. I can send you some references if you are interested! All the best.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this is to use `itertools.combinations` to pick out the indices of the final list into which you're going to put the elements of `l1`.  Then, for each of those choices, use `itertools.permutations` to find all permutations of items in the second list.  Then go through both of those lists, picking off of the front of either depending on whether the index is one that's supposed to be for an element for `l1` or `l2`.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ["x", "y"]

n = len(l1) + len(l2)

for c in combinations(range(0, n), len(l1)):
    cs = set(c)
    for p in permutations(l2):
        l1i = iter(l1)
        l2i = iter(p)
        print [ l1i.next() if i in cs else l2i.next() for i in range(0,n) ]
```

The output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y']
[1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x']
[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y']
[1, 2, 'y', 3, 'x']
[1, 2, 'x', 'y', 3]
[1, 2, 'y', 'x', 3]
[1, 'x', 2, 3, 'y']
[1, 'y', 2, 3, 'x']
[1, 'x', 2, 'y', 3]
[1, 'y', 2, 'x', 3]
[1, 'x', 'y', 2, 3]
[1, 'y', 'x', 2, 3]
['x', 1, 2, 3, 'y']
['y', 1, 2, 3, 'x']
['x', 1, 2, 'y', 3]
['y', 1, 2, 'x', 3]
['x', 1, 'y', 2, 3]
['y', 1, 'x', 2, 3]
['x', 'y', 1, 2, 3]
['y', 'x', 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Then to get the consistent order of `[1, 2, 3]`, you would just use `reversed`?

Comment: @Darthfett: oops, I meant `pop(0)` instead of `pop()` - fixed now

Comment: I think `reversed` might give better performance, as `pop(0)` is O(n), while `pop()` is O(1).  Given that you're popping all the items from the lists, it would save computation (which may be important when you're inside a combination permutation loop).

Comment: @Darthfett: good point.  I've actually made a slightly different change, though, just creating iterators for both and using `.next()`, which I hope is faster and clearer.

Answer (score 4):

I call this interspersing l1 with (the permutations of l2). You can do this in two steps: picking the positions, then permuting the positions. For insertion points, you can use a mask-based approach (`permutations([True,True,False,False,False])`) or an index-based approach (`product(*[range(5)]*2)`). Haven't gotten the latter technique to work yet.

```
from itertools import *

def interspersings(l1,l2):
    for mask in set(permutations([0]*len(l1) + [1]*len(l2))):  # sadly inefficient
        iters = [iter(l1), iter(l2)]
        yield [next(iters[which]) for which in mask]

for perm in permutations(l2):
    for interspersing in interspersings(l1,perm):
        print(interspersing)
```

Demo:

```
[1, 2, 'x', 'y', 3]
['x', 'y', 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y']
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y']
['x', 1, 'y', 2, 3]
[1, 'x', 'y', 2, 3]
[1, 'x', 2, 'y', 3]
['x', 1, 2, 'y', 3]
[1, 'x', 2, 3, 'y']
['x', 1, 2, 3, 'y']
[1, 2, 'y', 'x', 3]
['y', 'x', 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 'y', 3, 'x']
[1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x']
['y', 1, 'x', 2, 3]
[1, 'y', 'x', 2, 3]
[1, 'y', 2, 'x', 3]
['y', 1, 2, 'x', 3]
[1, 'y', 2, 3, 'x']
['y', 1, 2, 3, 'x']
```

**edit**: Ah, the latter technique I mentioned was correctly implemented by Mark Longair at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655695/711085 (it is much more efficient than this technique)

Comment: Why don't you use `itertools.repeat` instead of `[0]*` and `[1]*` ?

Comment: @rubik: readability, and they'll have to be expanded anyway to feed the call to `permutations`

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks you very much for helping.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Well, just use `chain` to chain the two repeats and you're done.

Comment: I think your code may be made efficient by using [`lexicographic permutations`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125/generate-permutations-of-list-with-repeated-elements). Also, as I see, your code may be adopted for a general case of more than 2 list (with some of them preserving order and some - not). And I don't see how Mark Longair's answer may handle more than 2 lists (though here I may be wrong about scalability of his approach).

Answer (score 1):

One of the better ways to approach this, I think, would be to keep [1,2,3] as is, and then, for 'x', recognize there are four locations it could be inserted (before '1', before '2', ... after '3'). Then, once 'x' has been inserted, there are now 5 places to insert 'y' (the three where 'x' was not inserted, plus before 'x' and after 'x'). Use a nested loop to insert 'x' and 'y' in each possible position. As a bonus, distill the nested loop into a comprehension...

Answer (score 0):

I tried something using a class place holder for l1 and `itertools.permutations` but it had duplicates in it.

So, trying again, this is the simplest I've been able to get it:

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations

l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = ["x", "y"]
r = range(len(l1)+len(l2))
for combo in combinations(r,len(l2)):
  for permu in permutations(l2):
    i1 = iter(l1).next
    i2 = iter(permu).next
    row = [ i2() if i in combo else i1() for i in r ]
    print row
```

Yielding:

```
['x', 'y', 1, 2, 3]
['y', 'x', 1, 2, 3]
['x', 1, 'y', 2, 3]
['y', 1, 'x', 2, 3]
['x', 1, 2, 'y', 3]
['y', 1, 2, 'x', 3]
['x', 1, 2, 3, 'y']
['y', 1, 2, 3, 'x']
[1, 'x', 'y', 2, 3]
[1, 'y', 'x', 2, 3]
[1, 'x', 2, 'y', 3]
[1, 'y', 2, 'x', 3]
[1, 'x', 2, 3, 'y']
[1, 'y', 2, 3, 'x']
[1, 2, 'x', 'y', 3]
[1, 2, 'y', 'x', 3]
[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y']
[1, 2, 'y', 3, 'x']
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y']
[1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = ['x', 'y', 0, 0, 0]
>>> l4 = []
>>> cyc = itertools.cycle(l1)
>>> for el in set(itertools.permutations(l2, 5)):
...     l4.append([cyc.next() if j==0 else j for j in el])
```

produces:

```
>>> l4
[[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y'], 
 ['y', 'x', 1, 2, 3], 
 ['x', 1, 'y', 2, 3], 
 ['x', 1, 2, 'y', 3], 
 [1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x'], 
 [1, 'y', 2, 3, 'x'], 
 [1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y'], 
 [1, 'x', 2, 3, 'y'], 
 [1, 'y', 'x', 2, 3], 
 [1, 2, 'x', 'y', 3], 
 [1, 2, 'y', 'x', 3], 
 [1, 'x', 2, 'y', 3], 
 ['y', 1, 2, 'x', 3], 
 ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'y'], 
 [1, 'y', 2, 'x', 3], 
 [1, 'x', 'y', 2, 3], 
 ['y', 1, 2, 3, 'x'], 
 ['x', 'y', 1, 2, 3], 
 [1, 2, 'y', 3, 'x'], 
 ['y', 1, 'x', 2, 3]]
```