# Iterate over lists with a certain number of 1s, 0s and -1s

Tags: python

I can iterate over all lists with -1s, 0s and 1s with

```
for v in itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat = n):
```

However, if I only want lists with A 1s, B 0s and C -1s, how can I iterate over those without making all the lists and filtering with `if v.count(1)=A and v.count(0) = B and v.count(C)=-1` ?

**EDIT**

Using itertools.permutations is very wasteful sadly as it makes the same tuple over and over again.

As `len(list(itertools.permutations([1]*2 + [0]*2 + [-1]*2))) = 720` although `len(set(itertools.permutations([1]*2 + [0]*2 + [-1]*2))) = 90`.

And we can see that permutations repeats tuples with

```
 print list(itertools.permutations([1]*1 + [0]*1 + [-1]*2))
[(1, 0, -1, -1), (1, 0, -1, -1), (1, -1, 0, -1), (1, -1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0, -1), (1, -1, -1, 0), (0, 1, -1, -1), (0, 1, -1, -1), (0, -1, 1, -1), (0, -1, -1, 1), (0, -1, 1, -1), (0, -1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, -1, 0), (-1, 0, 1, -1), (-1, 0, -1, 1), (-1, -1, 1, 0), (-1, -1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 0, -1), (-1, 1, -1, 0), (-1, 0, 1, -1), (-1, 0, -1, 1), (-1, -1, 1, 0), (-1, -1, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125/generate-permutations-of-list-with-repeated-elements

Comment: @thg435 Thanks although this comment looks worrying "Something wrong with this algorithm, it is also dependent on the initial order in sequence. Sequences [1,1,2,2,2] and [2,1,1,2,2] lead to different number of permutations.".

Comment: "Algorithm L" generates the _next_ permutation in the lexicographical sense. To get all of them, you have to start with a sorted sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using itertools.permutations will produce duplicates. You can code it up yourself, and here's one way to do it.

```
def uniq_perms(a, b, c):
    if a < 0 or b < 0 or c < 0:
        return
    if a + b + c == 0:
        yield []
    for s in uniq_perms(a - 1, b, c):
        yield [0] + s
    for s in uniq_perms(a, b - 1, c):
        yield [1] + s
    for s in uniq_perms(a, b, c - 1):
        yield [-1] + s

for s in uniq_perms(2, 1, 1):
    print s
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is actually [`permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) not [`product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

**Create a function to wrap this functionality:**

```
def foo(A, B, C):
    return itertools.permutations([1]*A + [0]*B + [-1]*C)
```

**Usage Example:**

```
>>> for v in foo(1,1,1):
    print v

(1, 0, -1)    (-1, 1, 0)
(-1, 0, 1)    (0, 1, -1)
(0, -1, 1)    (1, -1, 0)


>>> for v in foo(2,1,1):
    print v

(1, 1, 0, -1)    (1, 0, 1, -1)    (0, -1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, -1, 0)    (1, 0, -1, 1)    (0, -1, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1, -1)    (1, -1, 1, 0)    (-1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, 0, -1, 1)    (1, -1, 0, 1)    (-1, 1, 0, 1)
(1, -1, 1, 0)    (0, 1, 1, -1)    (-1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, -1, 0, 1)    (0, 1, -1, 1)    (-1, 1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0, -1)    (0, 1, 1, -1)    (-1, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, -1, 0)    (0, 1, -1, 1)    (-1, 0, 1, 1)
```

**Explanation:**

What you want to do is create a list which will be used to produce all the permutations, and you want this list to contain an amount of `-1,0,1`s as you want. Lets start with creating a list full of 5 1's. We can do that with:

```
>>> [1]*5
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

We can add this list to another list:

```
>>> [1]*5 + [0]*2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

And yet another:

```
>>> [1]*5 + [0]*2 + [-1]*7
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

And so, when you want to create your list, we get:

```
[1]*A + [0]*B + [-1]*C
```

Comment: The outputs doesn't always have 1 of each of the three options which is what I need in your example. (As n =2 it can't of course.) We need that A+B+C = n of course.

Comment: I think they want `itertools.permutations`

Comment: @marshall You are welcome to modify this any way you choose, but based on your original question - I have given you the solution you wanted.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. (0, 0) does not contain A 1s if A = 1, for example.

Comment: @marshall what @xymostech said. `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Thank you. There is something odd though.len(list(itertools.permutations([1]*2 + [0]*2 + [-1]*2))) = 720 and len(set(itertools.permutations([1]*2 + [0]*2 + [-1]*2))) = 90. It looks like permutations  is making the same list over and over again.

Comment: @marshall Permutations are not unique, as can also be seen in Inbar's example. You can easily check this with `list(itertools.permutations("aaaaa"))`, so using a `set` would be wise.

Comment: @tobias_k  Right.. How can I just get the unique ones directly without making the full list and filtering it or turning it into a set?

Comment: @marshall Not entirely sure, but I think `permutations` returns a generator object (would be surprised if not), so that should not be a problem, if you convert it straight into a set.

Comment: @marshall You are welcome to ask that as an entirely new question, and post that question as a comment here, I will gladly answer it. But I believe your original question is answered.