# implement combinatoric algorithm in c++("put apples in different plates")

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I generated a group of n-element arrays that consist of alternating 1 and -1 followed by zeros, all starting with 1.

For example, for n=5, the arrays are:
10000,
1-1000,
1-1100,
1-11-10,
1-11-11,

I need to “insert” the zeros between the non-zero numbers for each array:
For 1-1100 in the above example, the enumeration is:

1 -1 1 0 0,(allow some 1 and -1 to have no 0 between them.)

1 -1 0 1 0,

1 0 -1 1 0,

1 0 -1 0 1,

1 0 0 -1 1,

1 -1 0 0 1 (the first element still needs to be 1)

Is there a good algorithm to generate such enumeration for an given array with the above format?

I think the problem is like putting identical apples into different plates(because putting zeros into different gaps gives different enumeration) and allowing some plates to remain empty.

I need to print out all the possibilities, not just count them. But currently I can't figure out a good way to do it.

Comment: find the dash, set the element at the dash with zero, the next with dash, the next with 1, done

Comment: I've removed the [tag:c++] tag to save you from being downvoted. If you're really looking for a common algorithm then just ask for such. If you are looking for solutions with particular programming languages, you'll need to show at least what you've tried, and where you stuck in particular. May be this also is required for the [tag:algorithm] tag that the followers at least require you to give an idea in pseudo code notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simpler than it appears.

The first element is always 1. Thus, we can ignore that, and just
prepend 1 to our answers.

The nonzero elements, after the initial 1, are always -1, 1, -1, etc.
Since this pattern is fixed, we can replace all nonzeros with 1, then
translate back.

So now we just have a list of 0's and 1's and need to generate all their
permutations.

Putting it all together in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

N = 5

def main():
    # k = number of nonzeros, minus the initial one that's always there
    for k in range(N):
        seq = [0] * (N - 1 - k) + [1] * k
        for p in next_permutation(seq):
            result = decorate(p)
            print(" ".join("{:2d}".format(i) for i in result))

# adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125
def next_permutation(seq):
    seq = seq[:]
    first = 0
    last = len(seq)
    yield seq

    if last == 1:
        raise StopIteration

    while True:
        next = last - 1
        while True:
            next1 = next
            next -= 1
            if seq[next] < seq[next1]:
                mid = last - 1
                while seq[next] >= seq[mid]:
                    mid -= 1
                seq[next], seq[mid] = seq[mid], seq[next]
                seq = seq[:next1] + list(reversed(seq[next1:last])) + seq[last:]
                yield seq[:]
                break
            if next == first:
                raise StopIteration
    raise StopIteration

def decorate(seq):
    # Convert 1's to alternating -1, 1, then prepend a 1 to whole thing
    seq = seq[:]
    n = -1
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i]:
            seq[i] = n
            n = -n
    return [1] + seq

main()
```

Comment: Glad it was useful. Sorry for the Python. Last time I used C++ much was an OOPS course in '92 -- STL, wuzzat? :)