# all permutations of +-r, +-s

Tags: python, combinatorics, python-itertools

Given two numbers `r` and `s`, I would like to get a list of all permutations of `n` `+-r` and `m` `+-s`. For example (with `r=3.14` and `s=2.71`),

```
n = 1
m = 1
out = [
    (+r, +s), (+r, -s), (-r, +s), (-r, -s), 
    (+s, +r), (+s, -r), (-s, +r), (-s, -r)
    ]
```

```
n = 1
m = 2
out = [
    (+r, +s, +s), (+r, -s, +s), (-r, +s, +s), (-r, -s, +s), ...
    (+s, +r, +s), (-s, +r, +s), (+s, -r, +s), (-s, -r, +s), ...
    ...
    ]
```

With `itertools.product([+r, -r], repeat=n)` I can get the list of the `r`s and `s`s separately, and I'd only need to intertwine them, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do.

Efficiency is not overly important, so I wouldn't mind a solution that produces many repeated results only to make them unique afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** general solution added.

Here is a solution that is bit more complicated in code but does not produce repeated elements and can be evaluated lazily:

```
from itertools import combinations, product, chain

r = 3.14
s = 2.71
n = 1
m = 2
idx = combinations(range(n + m), n)
vs = ((r if j in i else s for j in range(n + m)) for i in idx)
res = chain.from_iterable(product(*((+vij, -vij) for vij in vi)) for vi in vs)
print("\n".join(map(str, res)))
```

Output:

```
(3.14, 2.71, 2.71)
(3.14, 2.71, -2.71)
(3.14, -2.71, 2.71)
(3.14, -2.71, -2.71)
(-3.14, 2.71, 2.71)
(-3.14, 2.71, -2.71)
(-3.14, -2.71, 2.71)
(-3.14, -2.71, -2.71)
(2.71, 3.14, 2.71)
(2.71, 3.14, -2.71)
(2.71, -3.14, 2.71)
(2.71, -3.14, -2.71)
(-2.71, 3.14, 2.71)
(-2.71, 3.14, -2.71)
(-2.71, -3.14, 2.71)
(-2.71, -3.14, -2.71)
(2.71, 2.71, 3.14)
(2.71, 2.71, -3.14)
(2.71, -2.71, 3.14)
(2.71, -2.71, -3.14)
(-2.71, 2.71, 3.14)
(-2.71, 2.71, -3.14)
(-2.71, -2.71, 3.14)
(-2.71, -2.71, -3.14)
```

**Explanation**

We can think of the output as permutations containing `n` +/- `r` elements and `m` +/- `s` elements, or, in other words, tuples of `n` + `m` elements where `n` are +/- `r` and the rest are +/- `s`. `idx` contains tuples with all the possible positions for +/- `r` elements; for example, for the first result it is `(0,)`.

Then, for each of these tuples `i` we create "template" tuples in `vs`, which are just tuples of size `n` + `m` where indices in `i` are `r` and the rest are `s`. So, for the tuple `(0,)` in `idx` you would get `(r, s, s)`. If `n` + `m` is very big you could consider a previous step `idx = map(set, idx)` for a faster `in` operation, but I'm not sure at which point that would be worth it.

Finally, for each of these templates `vi` in `v` I need to consider all the possibilities using a positive and negative value for each of its elements. So it is a Cartesian product of `(+vi[0], -vi[0]), (+vi[1], -vi[1]), ...`. And finally you just need to chain each of the generator of each of these products to get the final result.

**General solution**

To build a general solution to the problem for an arbitrary number of different elements, you need to consider *partitions* of the set of indices. For example, for `n = 3` and `m = 5`, all the possible ways you can split `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` in two parts of sizes 3 and 5. Here is an implementation for that:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat, permutations, product


def partitions(*sizes):
    if not sizes or all(s <= 0 for s in sizes):
        yield ()
    for i_size, size in enumerate(sizes):
        if size <= 0:
            continue
        next_sizes = sizes[:i_size] + (sizes[i_size] - 1,) + sizes[i_size + 1:]
        for p in partitions(*next_sizes):
            yield (i_size,) + p


def signed_permutations(*elems):
    values, sizes = zip(*elems)
    templates = partitions(*sizes)
    return chain.from_iterable(
        product(*((+values[ti], -values[ti]) for ti in t)) for t in templates)


r = 3.14
s = 2.71
n = 1
m = 2
res = signed_permutations((r, n), (s, m))
print("\n".join(map(str, res)))
```

The idea is the same, you build the "templates" (this time they contain indices of the values instead of the values themselves) and then the Cartesian products from them.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: `list(itertools.product(*([[+r, -r]] * 1 + [[+s, -s]] * 1)))` gives `[(3.14, 2.71), (3.14, -2.71), (-3.14, 2.71), (-3.14, -2.71)]` -- `3.14` is never in second place.

Comment: A word or two of explanation would certainly help understanding the code.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Right, I've added some explanations, let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` is probably advised here.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Yep, that's right, thanks, I've updated it.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Yet another update with a general solution for an arbitrary number of different elements.

Comment: Instead of your own `partitions`, one could use Knuth's "Algorithm L", implemented, e.g., at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125/generate-permutations-of-list-with-repeated-elements.

Answer (score 5):

You could also combine the `permutations` of `r` and `s` with the `product` of `+1` and `-1` and `zip` the two. This way, the entire construction is a bit more readable IMHO:

```
>>> n, m = 1, 2
>>> r, s = 3.14, 2.71
>>> [[x*i for x,i in zip(perm, prod)] for perm in permutations([r]*n + [s]*m) 
...                                   for prod in product((+1, -1), repeat=n+m)]
[[3.14, 2.71, 2.71],
 [3.14, 2.71, -2.71],
 ...
 [-2.71, -2.71, 3.14],
 [-2.71, -2.71, -3.14]]
```

Answer (score 4):

First use `product`, then `permutations` on each element. Then concatenate all results and pass them to `set()` for removing duplicates:

```
arr = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([
    itertools.permutations(x)
    for x in itertools.product(*([[+r, -r]] * n + [[+s, -s]] * m))
    ]))
print(arr)
```