# Python3 permutations with tuples that contain duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, duplicates, combinations, python-itertools

I want to create all the possible combinations of a tuple with duplicate elements.

For example lets say that we have {3,3,0}.
I want the code to return:
(3,3,0)
(3,0,3)
(0,3,3)

I looked at itertools documentation and at numerous stack overflow questions but i did not find a answer to this.

How can I implement it? Or, can this be implemented in general?

Comment: Is `{3,3,0}` your actual notation, that it being a `set`?

Comment: `from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations` For instance, `list(multiset_permutations([3,3,0]))` gives `[[0, 3, 3], [3, 0, 3], [3, 3, 0]]`

Comment: Yes, this was a set, although python makes it {3,0}.

Comment: @BillBell I do not want to add another package to this project, but thank you.

Comment: Just be aware that what you accepted will be comparatively slow.

Comment: I did not know it but I did not ask for a good (algorithmicly good) answer too. So i think it would be wrong not to accept it. Can you suggest something faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from itertools and then use a `set` to remove any doubles:

```
result = set(permutations((3, 3, 0)))
```

Comment: Nice! thank you. I literally just found another way too. I am such a noob with python...
The other way is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125/generate-permutations-of-list-with-repeated-elements

Answer (score 2):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library:

`> pip install more_itertools`

Code

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = (3, 3, 0)
list(mit.distinct_permutations(iterable))
# [(3, 3, 0), (3, 0, 3), (0, 3, 3)]
```

See [`more_itertools` docs](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations) for details.

Comment: :)  You can only accept one.  @Mureinik's answer is pythonic and requite acceptable.  This one may be a bit faster.