# Efficiently find full row permutations in 2d array having repeated row pairs

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-itertools, numpy-indexed

Consider the array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi
from itertools import permutations

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [3, 3, 3, 6],
                [2, 0, 0, 2],
                [2, 0, 0, 2],  
                [8, 2, 8, 2],
                [4, 5, 4, 5], 
                [3, 3, 3, 6],
                [4, 5, 4, 5],
                [0, 9, 8, 7],
                [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

I need to find **all unique row permutations**.  What I currently do is find all **10! row permutations**, then use `npi.unique`.  Like this:

```
arr_perms = np.array([arr[i, :] for i in permutations(range(len(arr)))])
u, index = npi.unique(arr_perms, return_index = True, axis=0)
```

This works as expected, but it seems expensive because of the nature of the arrays I am working with.  **These arrays all have at least one pair (usually several pairs) of identical rows**.

In the small example shown, the 10 rows hold 4 identical row pairs, so the total number of unique row permutqtions is only `10!/2^4 = 226800`,  a big reduction.

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to efficiently find the unique row permutations without first having to find the full set of permutations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250125/generate-permutations-of-list-with-repeated-elements

Comment: not really - this refers to repeated elements in a list.   I'm asking about repeated ENTIRE ROWS in a numpy array.  The code I gave correctly produces all unique full-row permutations, but I'm hoping to get a more efficient solution that doesn't involve first computing ALL permutations, then weeding out the doubles.

Comment: If you run `np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True, axis=0)`, you can reduce the original array to a series of integers representing an index into the unique values. The permutations of these integers are the same thing as the permutations of the rows.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use [distinct_permutations](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_permutations) to avoid constructing the duplicate permutations initially.

Comment: @Nick ODell - This leads to an excellent resolution of the problem that, as requested, avoids building the full set of permutations.   Thank you.   Do you have any interest in posting this as an 'Answer' for the benefit of others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here might help you. It still creates all permutations, but it is 10 times faster than the code you posted, since each subarray of length 4 is converted to an int using bit shifting.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import numpy_indexed as npi


def generate_permutations_matrix(n, k):
    """
    Generate a matrix of permutations for given values of n and k.

    Parameters:
    - n (int): Total number of elements.
    - k (int): Length of each permutation.

    Returns:
    - np.ndarray: Matrix of permutations.
    """
    result_matrix = np.zeros((math.perm(n, k), k), np.uint8)
    f = 1
    for m in range(n - k + 1, n + 1):
        sub_matrix = result_matrix[:f, n - m + 1:]
        for i in range(1, m):
            result_matrix[i * f: (i + 1) * f, n - m] = i
            result_matrix[i * f: (i + 1) * f, n - m + 1:] = sub_matrix + (
                    sub_matrix >= i
            )
        sub_matrix += 1
        f *= m
    return result_matrix


def convert_to_integer(arr):
    """
    Convert a 2D array of integers to a single integer value.

    Parameters:
    - arr (np.ndarray): Input 2D array.

    Returns:
    - int: Integer representation of the array.
    """
    arr = arr.astype(np.uint64)
    integer_value = arr[..., 0].copy()
    for ival in range(1, arr.shape[1]):
        integer_value += arr[..., ival] << ival * 8
    return integer_value


def get_permutations(arr, len_of_each):
    """
    Get unique permutations of rows in a 2D array.

    Parameters:
    - arr (np.ndarray): Input 2D array.
    - len_of_each (int): Length of each permutation.

    Returns:
    - np.ndarray: Permutations matrix.
    """
    integer_value = convert_to_integer(arr)

    # Create dictionaries for mapping integer values to unique identifiers
    lookup_dict = {}
    lookup_dict2 = {}
    alpha1 = []
    identifier = 0

    # Iterate through integer values and create mappings
    for ini, x in enumerate(integer_value):
        if x in lookup_dict:
            value = lookup_dict.get(x)
            alpha1.append((value, x))
            lookup_dict2[ini] = value
        else:
            alpha1.append((identifier, x))
            lookup_dict[x] = identifier
            lookup_dict2[ini] = identifier
            identifier += 1

    # Generate permutations matrix
    permutations_matrix = generate_permutations_matrix(len(alpha1), len_of_each)

    # Map original identifiers back to permutations matrix
    cond_list = []
    choice_list = []
    for nom in lookup_dict2.items():
        cond_list.append(permutations_matrix == nom[0])
        choice_list.append(nom[1])

    choice_list = np.array(choice_list, dtype=np.uint8)
    unique_permutations = npi.unique(
        np.select(cond_list, choice_list, 0), return_index=False, axis=0
    )

    # Map back to original identifiers
    cond_list2 = []
    choice_list2 = []
    for nom in lookup_dict.items():
        cond_list2.append(unique_permutations == nom[1])
        choice_list2.append(nom[0])

    result = np.select(cond_list2, choice_list2, 0)

    # Convert back to the original 2D array format
    return np.stack(
        [
            np.dstack([(result[..., g] >> rx * 8) & 255 for rx in range(arr.shape[1])])
            for g in range(len_of_each)
        ],
        axis=2,
    ).squeeze()


# Example usage
arr = np.array(
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [3, 3, 3, 6],
        [2, 0, 0, 2],
        [2, 0, 0, 2],
        [8, 2, 8, 2],
        [4, 5, 4, 5],
        [3, 3, 3, 6],
        [4, 5, 4, 5],
        [0, 9, 8, 7],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
    ]
)
result_permutations = get_permutations(arr=arr, len_of_each=10)

from itertools import permutations


def test(arr):
    arr_perms = np.array([arr[i, :] for i in permutations(range(len(arr)))])
u, index = npi.unique(arr_perms, return_index=True, axis=0)
return u, index

%timeit result_permutations = get_permutations(arr=arr, len_of_each=10)
1.52 s ± 27.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test(arr)
13.6 s ± 52.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Detailed and clear solution that is quite fast!  Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! I had to solve the same problem as you on the weekend :) I ended up implementing the code in Cython which does the job in a little under a second.  It's on GitHub, in case you want to use it: https://github.com/hansalemaos/permutation_no_repetition/blob/main/__init__.py  You need Cython and a C/C++ compiler to run it.